# Spring Boot + PostgreSQL: HibernateException on field with datatype "interval" on .save()

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring boot app and want to save an object in my table.
Entity class:

```
import de.mine.postgresexample.DurationConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;

import java.time.Duration;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Areas\"")
public class Area {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "timespan", columnDefinition = "interval")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.DURATION)
    @Convert(converter = DurationConverter.class)
    private Duration timespan;
}
```

I try to convert the java.time.Duration using my converter.

```
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter
import jakarta.persistence.Converter

import java.time.Duration

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class DurationConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, String> {
    @Override
    String convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration duration) {
        return duration != null ? duration.toString() : null
    }

    @Override
    Duration convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData != null ? Duration.parse(dbData) : null
    }
}
```

With `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` the following table gets created on startup:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table areas
(
    id               serial
        primary key,
    timespan         interval
);
```

Then I try to save an entity like this:

```
Area area = new Area()
area.timespan = Duration.ofHours(1)
areaRepository.save(area)
```

This fails due to this exception which is not helping me fixing the issue:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not convert 'java.lang.String' to 'java.math.BigDecimal' using 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType' to unwrap
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeHelper.unknownUnwrap(JavaTypeHelper.java:20) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractClassJavaType.unknownUnwrap(AbstractClassJavaType.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType.unwrap(StringJavaType.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType.unwrap(StringJavaType.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.DecimalJdbcType$1.doBind(DecimalJdbcType.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.lambda$beforeStatement$0(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.spi.BindingGroup.forEachBinding(BindingGroup.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.beforeStatement(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.performInsert(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.execute(MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:754) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:319) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:618) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy114.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:321) ~[groovy-4.0.18.jar:4.0.18]
    at de.mine.postgresexample.TestController.test(TestController.groovy:22) ~[main/:na]
```

Is there a way to get this working properly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the error message? You are trying to store a String in an `interval` typed column, which is a numeric type not a character based type. Either change the interval type to `varchar` or convert to a numeric type (a BigDecimal as in the exception). Or just remove your converter (and the `@Basic`) and I suspect Hibernate might do the transformation automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to PostgreSQL and this interval type is really challenging. Anyway, changing the converter to
    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration duration) {
        if (duration != null) {
            return BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.toMillis())
        }
        return null
    }
gives me: ERROR: column "timespan" is of type interval but expression is of type numeric. You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
This is the exact same message I get when removing the converter too.